# Difference between valuable and of value

Tags: word-choice

Do the following two sentences have the same meaning? Which one looks better or more natural? Thanks!

1. Organised by xxx, “Ten Good Books” recommends the ten books of the highest value to readers.
2. Organised by xxx, “Ten Good Books” recommends the ten most valuable books to readers.

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence looks better and more natural with some minor changes. i.e.

> Organised by xxx, “Ten Good Books” recommends the ten most valuable books to ***the***/***it's*** readers.

Reason:-
***Valuable*** means of high monetary or material value or of great importance, utility, or service while ***of value*** means highly esteemed.

So, according to the meaning of the sentence, the ten good books hold a very important role for the reader. That is why i suggest the use of the word valuable.

Comment: I have voted this down as the sentences given by the OP have different meanings and you have not recognised this. As they are different, they cannot be compared.

Comment: @user178255 1. refers to books that the readers will value most. 2. refers to the most expensive books.

Comment: @Greybeard, as you read the question the second part of the question asks: 'Which one looks better or more natural?'. so I simply answered that question. I altered the answer as the sentence was grammetically incomplete. I have also stated the reason as to why i have selected the particular response.

Comment: The OP is asking for a comparison. You cannot give an opinion on which of two completely different things is better. If I ask "What is better, a monkey or a lamppost", how can you give an answer?